# Process Builder only calling invocable methods for top 3 records when uploading via DataLoader.io

Tags: apex, process-builder, data-loader, invocable-method, dataloader.io

First time posting and I'm quite new to SF. I've ended up on this site a lot when Googling to help me with issues - so thanks!

On my org, we're uploading some opportunities via DataLoader.io that will then send emails out to external contacts.

This was done via process builder - the opportunity has a specific record type and stage for the process to be followed. While it does complete the first action for all the records(which is a simple record update), the 2nd action is to call an invocable method to send the email out. In this case it's only actioning the first 3 records in the upload for the invocable method.

```
Global class sendInvoiceSurvey {


    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendInvoiceEmail(List<opportunity>InvoiceContact){

   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   mail.setTargetObjectId(InvoiceContact[0].Fee_Contact__c);
   mail.setTemplateId('00X24000000F1iy'); 

   mail.setSaveAsActivity(true); 
   mail.setWhatId(InvoiceContact[0].Id);
   mail.setBccSender(true);
   mail.setSenderDisplayName('INSP');

         Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

} }
```

I'm really lost as to why this is only working the first 3 records. Are there any limits that is preventing other emails going out? Or an issue with my code/process?

Any help would massively appreciated!

Comment: Can you update your code in your question. It seems that all of your lines are commented because there were problems with the line breaks.

Comment: There's something I don't understand. In your function you receive a list of `InvoiceContact`. But you only send an email to the first record of your list.

Comment: Could this be where my issue is? So the process builder should work on creation of a new opportunity record, which I thought would make sense in only sending 1 email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said as comment, you don't loop through the list of `InvoiceContact`.

Here's the solution:

```
Global class sendInvoiceSurvey {


    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendInvoiceEmail(List<opportunity>InvoiceContact){

   List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
   for(Opportunity opp : InvoiceContact){
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.Fee_Contact__c);
   mail.setTemplateId('00X24000000F1iy'); 

   mail.setSaveAsActivity(true); 
   mail.setWhatId(opp.Id);
   mail.setBccSender(true);
   mail.setSenderDisplayName('INSP');

   mails.add(mail);
   }

         Messaging.sendEmail(mails);

} }
```

With this code, you instanciate one email object for each of opportunity received and send all the emails.

Comment: Thanks so much - I can clearly see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.